# Нужно выбрать и реализовать алгоритм шифрования

Tags: php, laravel, криптография

Стоит задача - передавать id пользователя на субдомен, чтоб этот пользователь стал авторизованным (без запроса логина и пароля). Передавать нужно GET-ом. 
Значит, этот id нужно зашифровать так, чтобы нельзя было сочинить шифр какого-то другого числа. То есть что-то типа "умножить на три и прибавть два"- не катит. 
Посоветуйте, от чего оттолкнуться? Где начать поиск? Или самому велосипедить?

Comment: Не совсем понятен ваш вопрос. Для чего это вообще нужно? И для чего шифровать id?

Comment: Это нужно для того, чтоб пеерходить от одного субдомена к другому, сохраняя авторизацию пользователя (не спрашщивая у него логин/пароль). Шифровать id нужно для того, чтобы злой человек не залогинился, просто введя ?id=45

Comment: А почему не выставить cookie для всех субдоменов?

Comment: Так он же должен сначала зайти, чтоб выставить куку. "Нет прописки - нет работы, нет работы - нет прописки".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id можете передавать хоть в открытом виде. помимо него передаете хеш (что нибудь из SHA, или md5 на худой конец) от строки содержащей этот id и некое секретное слово. Домен на который вы переходите, берет id из параметра, строит такую же строку, считает хеш, сверяет с переданным. Подделка, без знания секретного слова, которое есть только в вашем коде, не возможна.

Но по такой ссылке можно войти когда угодно, просто найдя ссылку в истории браузера, хоть через 10 лет. Поэтому, если вы делаете редирект, т.е. пользователь переходит по ссылке автоматически, сразу после того, как вы ее создали, более правильным решением будет передавать еще и текущее время (можно отдельным параметром), которое разумеется то же входит в хеш. Проверяющая сторона убеждается, что скажем прошло менее 5 секунд с момента формирования ссылки и обменивает ссылку на свои куки. Если это не так, ссылка выдана в браузер в виде `<A HREF...>`, то вы не можете знать сколько времени пройдет, но можете включить в хеш например ip пользователя. Хотя такие ссылки лучше было бы заменить на ссылки на специальный редиректор на текущем домене. Пользователь переходит по текущему домену, тот проверяет авторизацию, генерит ссылку с хешем и временем, 
делает редирект на нее.